# Can i programatically obtain services metadata/name/url in Spring Cloud?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

Is it possible to programatically display all of the services (names + URL) of the services registered to Eureka service registry and is it possible to do the same for API gateway (Zuul) registered to any Eureka service registry (for example i suppose it is possible to read this metadata from the ApplicationContext)?

Comment: Have you looked at the DiscoveryClient interface?